# Download GitHub Pull Request description images remotely or via the API

Tags: github, github-api, pull-request

### Background

When someone merges a pull request into a private repository in GitHub, I want to show the details of the Pull Request, including the images in the description, in another location (Slack). Usually these are short videos or screenshots of what has changed, so it would be great to have a continuous stream of changes visible to everyone in slack.

### The problem

From what I can tell looking at the [GitHub API Docs](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/pulls/pulls?apiVersion=2022-11-28#get-a-pull-request), there is no way to download these images via the API.

The images are stored at URL's like `https://github.com/owner/project-name/assets/*` that are not publicly accessible. So you have to be logged into the browser to actually get access to the image.

When you **do** view an image in the browser, GitHub redirects you to a short-lived URL that looks like `https://private-user-images.githubusercontent.com/123456/251885706-e74af325-a947-47f7-8dad-61129ad62f11.png?jwt=eyJ...`. This URL **is** public, but again, I want to generate that URL without being logged into the browser so that I can do this in response to a webhook.

### Example

For example, the PR description might have something like this:

```markdown
Did a bunch of cool stuff in this one...

## What it looks like
<img width="1238" alt="Screenshot 2023-07-07 at 6 28 14 PM" 
src="https://github.com/owner/project-name/assets/123456/e74af324-a944-47f4-8da4-61129ad62f14">
```

What I want to know is how to download the image located at https://github.com/owner/project-name/assets/123456/e74af324-a944-47f4-8da4-61129ad62f14 remotely with a script.

Answer (score 2):

Get your `user_session` Cookie from your browser and provision a token to access Github API.

```bash
export GH_TOKEN="<token>"
export GH_SESSION_COOKIE="<session_cookie>"
python download.py "<owner>/<repo>/pulls/<pr_number>"
```

### Content of download.py

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import os
import sys
import urllib.request
import json
import re
from urllib.parse import urlparse


def main():
    # Read GH_TOKEN and GH_SESSION_COOKIE from environment variables
    gh_token = os.environ["GH_TOKEN"]
    gh_session_cookie = os.environ["GH_SESSION_COOKIE"]

    # Set pull request number & repo name
    path_segment = sys.argv[1]

    # Get URL regexp
    url_regexp = re.compile(r"https?://[^\"]+")

    headers = {
        "Accept": "application/vnd.github+json",
        "Authorization": f"Bearer {gh_token}",
        "X-GitHub-Api-Version": "2022-11-28"
    }

    # Download the pull request body
    req = urllib.request.Request(
        f"https://api.github.com/repos/{path_segment}", headers=headers)
    resp = urllib.request.urlopen(req)

    # Get all occurrences of URL like patterns using RegExp
    body = json.loads(resp.read().decode('utf-8'))['body']

    urls = url_regexp.findall(body)

    # Download files from URLs
    for url in urls:
        headers = {
            "cookie": f"user_session={gh_session_cookie};"
        }
        req = urllib.request.Request(url, headers=headers)
        with urllib.request.urlopen(req) as u:

            # Get the file name from the URL
            filename = urlparse(u.geturl()).path.split('/')[-1]

            with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
                f.write(u.read())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

### Caveat

`session_cookie` is only valid for [2 weeks](https://github.com/privacy/cookies). Extra care must be taken to keep it secret as that cookie allows to impersonate your Github account.

Comment: That seems more accurate than my answer. Upvoted.

Answer (score 0):

When I look at [VSCode PR 187953](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/187953) (which has a picture in it), I see its json with https://api.github.com/repos/microsoft/vscode/pulls/187953

It gives, using [gh pr view](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_pr_view) (but a `curl` would work too):

```
gh pr view -R microsoft/vscode 187953 --jq ".body" --json body

So that there isn't such a large gap at the bottom.

![image](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/assets/2644648/dee6499a-cbec-460f-893b-cc5bccadc853)


<!-- Thank you for submitting a Pull Request. Please:
* Read our Pull Request guidelines:
  https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/wiki/How-to-Contribute#pull-requests
* Associate an issue with the Pull Request.
* Ensure that the code is up-to-date with the `main` branch.
* Include a description of the proposed changes and how to test them.
-->
```

And a `curl -kL https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/assets/2644648/dee6499a-cbec-460f-893b-cc5bccadc853 -o res.png` gives me the PNG file. I did not set any Authentication header.
In other words, I was not logged in to get the final PNG file.

Comment: I believe the repository in question is private.

Comment: @PaulBrit Than nothing would be accessible without being authenticated, one way or the other. Let us wait for the OP to confirm the repo visibility.

Comment: The OP actually mentioned a github token in the _ draw more attention_ section: 
"To win the bounty, you need a script in python (or a similar language) that I can run with just a github token to download one of these images"

Comment: @PaulBrit Subtle, but makes sense.